# Laravel 'hasOne' between two mongo db table how (mongodb & laravel Experts)?

Tags: mongodb, laravel, relationship

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tgV4.jpg)

i want to join "_id" in user table with "user_id" in Comment table. please help me to resolve this issue. can you give me proper solution for hasone relationship between two model

```
User table in mongodb
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("59784d8f82956de05700003a"),
  "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-07-27T05:02:04.000Z"),
  "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-26T08:06:39.000Z"),
}


Comment Table in mongo db
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("59787c5782956ddc57000041"),
   "updated_at" : ISODate("2017-07-28T13:05:17.000Z"),
   "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-26T11:26:15.000Z"),
   "replycomments" : [ 
     {
    "user_id" : "592cfcced5429ba9fc091fa0",
    "created_at" : ISODate("2017-07-28T13:05:17.000Z")
     }
  ]
}



public function user()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users', '_id', 'user_id');
}
```

Comment: do you have Model for both table in your laravel application

Comment: yes i have Model for Both table

Comment: are you understand my question very well ?
if not then you can see description in Image Link, please refer that image

Comment: a user has one comment and by the user, you want that comment right?

Comment: Yes, i have Comment table in nested user Comments have many Comment.
Like This, i wan to retrieve user_id from user Table using hasOne methos

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("597aca2e82956de857000047"),
 
    "replycomments" : [ 
        {

            "user_id" : "592cfcced5429ba9fc091fa0",

        }, 
        {

            "user_id" : "592cfcced5429ba9fc091fa0",

        }, 
        {

            "user_id" : "592cfcced5429ba9fc091fa0",

        }
    ]
}

Comment: Can we do something like
public function user()
{
   return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Users', '_id', replycomments.'user_id');
}

Answer (score 1):

in your User Model add a function

```
public get_comment(){
return $this->hasOne('App\Comment','user_id','_id');
}
```

suppose I am fetching data of a user from user table and I want the comment from the comment table   now to get the data :

```
$user = User::findOrFail($id);
```

now print the value to check :

```
dd($user->get_comment->replycomments);
```

Comment: let me do this, Thanks for replay

Comment: Where do i add this ?
$user = User::findOrFail($id);

Comment: in your controller

Comment: In which controller, user or Comment ??

Comment: User controller but it depends where you want your data

Comment: and where i can put this ?

dd($user->get_comment->replycomments);

Comment: this line is just to print your data in controller to check did u get right data or not